# How to show profile picture of user logged in asp.net mvc 5 using asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I`m using asp.net identity and i have added a property for profile image in the application user class, so when i register new users i just add image URL and they show fine in page.

So how can i get the image profile icon of logged in users on the navbar just like on the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please show some code of your page to explain your problem. Basically you can set a img tag with src attribute anchored to `ViewBag`/`ViewData` which holds your image URL like `<img src="@ViewBag.Image" />`, based from user name.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto it`s a standard mvc web application with asp.net identity, im using the template from vs2015 no code of mine is added, just one property for image path...

Comment: This post helped me, very clear and to the point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517348/mvc-5-show-custom-profile-in-shared-layout/21520134#21520134